# How to install a docker on a virtual machine on MacBook Pro with a M1 chip?

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v

I am doing this internship where my supervisor told me to install a docker on a virtual machine.
I am using MacBook Pro with M1 chip Ventura 13.1.
What should I do?

(TBH I don't think my supervisor knows how this works too. I am just a sophomore trying to gain some experience. Our conversation looks like this:
He: Install docker on a virtual machine and let me know when done.
Me: What operating system should this virtual machine has? Is it Windows 11 64-bit Arm?
He: Install docker on a virtual machine and let me know when done.
Me: What?? What OS should it be?
He: So you can't complete the task right?
Me: ????)

I have tried downloading virtual box but it warned me: "Unsupported hardware architecture detected! The installer has detected an unsupported architecture. VirtualBox only runs on the amd64 architecture."
So I tried to download and configured VMware using this tutorial:
[vmware tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt5FIO_I-qo)
Everything was set up and I downloaded docker. But I cannot open it, I get this warning: Docker Desktop is unable to detect a hypervisor Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in BIOS.   I could not find solution to this as well.
Then I tried to use ubuntu virtual machine following this blog:  [Docker on macOS at native speed using Ubuntu Virtual Machine (both Intel and Apple Silicon CPU)](https://medium.com/carvago-development/my-docker-on-macos-part-1-setup-ubuntu-virtual-machine-both-intel-and-apple-silicon-cpu-5d886af0ebba)   Then when I reached this step: screen /dev/ttys003 (mine was ttys001), it just kept failing.
I need some help...Many thanks!

Comment: Docker principally runs on Linux (and Docker Desktop uses a hidden Linux VM generally) and you might install a Linux VM here.  Is this question just about creating the VM, or if there a more specific programming-related question?

Comment: @DavidMaze This is more about creating the VM. How should I install a Linux VM here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Docker Desktop for Mac, it already runs in a Linux Hypervisor. There is no need to install additional VM software, and you definitely don't need Windows 10/11

If you wanted to use Ubuntu, I guess you could use [Multipaas](https://multipass.run/docs/use-docker-blueprint) on a Mac